# Нужно считывать статус оформления по рег. номеру

Tags: c#

Я начинающий в c# и это мой первый вопрос. 
Мне нужно взять с этого сайта http://mon.declarant.by/vpto/search> Тип, рег. номер, дату регистрации и когда был изменен Статус и сам статус. Парсить обычные сайты  я могу, но вот на этом сайте есть кнопка подгрузить еще, которая ставит меня в ступор.Подскажите как это лучше сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо:

1. Скачать html используя [WebClient.DownloadString Метод](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring?view=netcore-3.1)
2. Подключить библиотеку HtmlAgilityPack через NuGet.
3. Распарсить html. Для этого вам потребуется писать XPath. В Google Chrome необходимо нажать правой клавишей мыши на элемент и выбрать Inspect.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как поступить с "подгрузить еще"?

Comment: Пожалуй вы правы. Нужно итерировать страницы: http://mon.declarant.by/api/pto-recs?page=2
В этом случае шаги 2 и 3 стоит отменить. Вместо этого вам стоит использовать библиотеку Newtonsoft.Json, которую можно установить из NuGet.

Comment: Буду разбираться, спасибо.